# In sql server, how do i group rows that have same values in a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT pd.trackingno                                                AS [Parcel],
         Trim(o.orderno) + '_'
         + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, pd.groupnum )                            AS [Order],
         Isnull(vi.[gtin], '''')                                      AS [Item],
         Isnull(i.skuno, '')                                          AS [Article],
         Isnull(ix_clr.skuno, '')                                     AS [Color],
         Isnull(ix_sze.skuno, '')                                     AS [Size],
         Isnull(i.[description], '')                                  AS [Description],
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 2), oi.unitprice * oi.quantity)           AS [Price],
         CONVERT(INT, oi.quantity)                                    AS [Sent]
  FROM   (SELECT orderno,
                 'S' Type,
                 groupnum
          FROM   shipments
          WHERE  shipbatch BETWEEN '2018-04-26 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-27 00:00:00') ords
         INNER JOIN orders AS o
                 ON o.orderno = ords.orderno
         INNER JOIN packageTable AS pd
                 ON ords.orderno = pd.orderno
                    AND ords.groupnum = pd.groupnum
         INNER JOIN oiTable oi
                 ON oi.orderno = ords.orderno
                    AND Isnull(ords.groupnum, 0) = Isnull(oi.groupnum, 0)
         INNER JOIN detailsTable AS od
                 ON ords.orderno = od.orderno
                    AND oi.linenum = od.linenum
         INNER JOIN itemsTable i
                 ON od.itemid = i.itemid
         left JOIN itemXref ix_clr
                 ON i.itemid = ix_clr.itemid
                    AND ix_clr.skutype = 'CLR'
         left JOIN itemXref ix_sze
                 ON i.itemid = ix_sze.itemid
                    AND ix_sze.skutype = 'SZE'
         INNER JOIN vItemTables vi
                 ON vi.itemid = od.itemid
  GROUP  BY pd.trackingno,
            o.orderno,
            pd.groupnum,
            vi.gtin,
            i.skuno,
            ix_clr.skuno,
            ix_sze.skuno,
            i.description,
            o.tax,
            oi.unitprice,
            oi.quantity
```

which generates the below output:

```
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
|    Parcel     |   Order   |      Item      |  Alias   | Color |  Size  | Price | Sent |
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
| DPV0010260188 | DHRU124_1 | 00717851968853 | 9E9D2256 | Red   | MEDIUM |  2.00 |    1 |
| DPV0010260188 | DHRU124_1 | 00717851968853 | 9E9D2256 | Red   | MEDIUM |     1 |    1 |
| DPV0010260188 | DHRU124_1 | 00021331918437 | 9782189D |       |        |     4 |    1 |
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
```

As you can see, except for the send field, the rest of the data is same. It need not be same all the time.Alias are basically items inside a package. So i want to group the rows together based on the alias value and sum up their price and sent value. So that it could be read as order and the number of same items and their total price.
Attached screenshot has the table values for reference
[image: Table values]

Expected output:

```
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
|    Parcel     |   Order   |      Item      |  Alias   | Color |  Size  | Price | Sent |
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
| DPV0010260188 | DHRU124_1 | 00717851968853 | 9E9D2256 | Red   | MEDIUM |  3.00 |    2 |
| DPV0010260188 | DHRU124_1 | 00021331918437 | 9782189D |       |        |     4 |    1 |
+---------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+
```

Comment: For future posts... pictures are usually not preferred. Plain text is far better, the majority of the time.

Comment: Also, sample data with expected outcome is usually very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can find your answer here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply this to your current query, I would most likely use a variable table, to store the results from your query in, and then query the variable table like this...

```
declare @example table (
    ExampleID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key clustered
,   Parcel  nvarchar(255) not null
,   [Order] nvarchar(255) not null
,   Item    nvarchar(255) not null
,   Alias   nvarchar(255) not null
,   Color   nvarchar(255) null
,   Size    nvarchar(255) null
,   Price   money not null
,   [Sent]  int not null
);

insert into @example (Parcel, [Order], Item, Alias, Color, Size, Price, [Sent])

select 'DPV0010260188' , 'DHRU124_1' , '00717851968853' , '9E9D2256' , 'Red'   , 'MEDIUM' ,  2.00 ,    1 union all
select 'DPV0010260188' , 'DHRU124_1' , '00717851968853' , '9E9D2256' , 'Red'   , 'MEDIUM' ,     1 ,    1 union all
select 'DPV0010260188' , 'DHRU124_1' , '00021331918437' , '9782189D' , null    , null     ,     4 ,    1;

select distinct Parcel
     , [Order]
     , Item
     , Alias
     , Color
     , Size
     , sum(Price) Price
     , sum([Sent]) [Sent]
  from @example
  group by Parcel, [Order], Item, Alias, Color, Size
```

> Output:

```
Parcel          Order       Item            Alias       Color   Size    Price   Sent
DPV0010260188   DHRU124_1   00021331918437  9782189D    NULL    NULL    4.00    1
DPV0010260188   DHRU124_1   00717851968853  9E9D2256    Red     MEDIUM  3.00    2
```

Comment: @AswinFrancis any questions? did this help?

Comment: thank you so much. I totally forgot about this approach. I was able to use your code and get it to work as i needed and it works fine now. Thanks again :)